# Loop python while typing words into a document then looping back around again. How would I do this?

Tags: python, loops, file

I basically want to type a word over and over into a document. But how do I type words line by line without for word in f:. I want it to keep going and loop back around to the beginning of the file.

```
import pyautogui, time, keyboard
time.sleep(10)
f= open("bot",'r')
for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            break
```

Comment: this wouldn't be possible without a loop because this is what loops are designed for

Comment: @reece is there any way to make it loop though?

Comment: `for word in f:` is a loop

Comment: @reece but make it wrap back around and keep sending old words after exhausting the file

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the 'for' loop to continuously keep running and updating the file even after it has terminated you can contain it under a while loop like,

```
import pyautogui, time, keyboard
time.sleep(10)

while(1):
    f= open("bot",'r')
    if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
        break  
    for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: This won't work. The file is exhausted after the for loop has completed for the first time.

Comment: Hmm but the loop doesn't loop the file back. It still stops typing after there are no more words instead of going back again

Comment: @TwSMatt I have updated my code and this should work now. This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it because I am opening the file every time in the loop.

Comment: Please use a ``with`` statement to handle the file lifetime, if you repeatedly open and close it.